# Magento 2 - Add reviews list in theme template

Tags: magento2, template, theme, review

I need to show a list of latest reviews on magento 2 homepage.
I did it this way

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $reviewCollection->create()->load();

foreach ($collection as $review){
 echo $review->getTitle().'<br>';
}  ?>
```

But I feel like its a bad practice, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are always better solutions.

In order to make these kind of things more reusable, one better way would be to make your reviews into a widget. Create `etc/widget.xml` in your module and point it to a `Block` class that you create.

In that `Block` class you can set a `mytemplate.phtml` template. Now you have separated the code from the layout, which is a better way. Also widgets can have configuration parameters, for example you could make the number configurable after which you stop displaying reviews (imagine there are thousands of reviews in your system, you probably don't want to load them all).

Furthermore, the `ObjectManager` should never be used directly. Instead, your `CollectionFactory` should be instantiated through [Dependency Injection](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) in the constructor. Alan Storm has written a very good [tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento2_dependency_injection_2015) about that.